# How to give back link to grid from custom admin phtml file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, redirect

I have **custom Admin grid** in my magento 2.

In that each row has view link when I click on `view` it opens complete details (same as Edit) after that I should come back to admin grid when I click on `Back button/link` in that (view) `phtml` file.

How Do I achieve this ? Actually redirect url we can use in controller but in **custom phtml** what we should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways to achieve that.. you can play with sessions to achieve that but I found the easiest way to achieve this is by Java script..

`href="javascript: history.go(-1)"`

In your back button give the above URL.

Or if you want the Magento way then you can refer the below Ans.

[Magento 2 how to make go back button on custom admin page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133011/magento-2-how-to-make-go-back-button-on-custom-admin-page/133034)